# Crankshaft won’t rotate

Tags: honda, timing-belt, pilot

2012 Honda Pilot Crankshaft stop rotating after timing belt was replaced. Can I rotate counterclockwise or take the belt back off a force cams to rotate?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What do you mean "it won't rotate"? I'm taking it you replaced the belt and now the crank will only rotate so far, but then stops? Whatever you do, don't force it. And if you "have" to rotate it in reverse, sometimes you have to do what you have to do even though it's not recommended.

Comment: Thank you. Take the belt off and attempt this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking it you replaced the belt and now the crank will only rotate so far, but then stops? Whatever you do, don't force it. And if you "have" to rotate it in reverse, sometimes you have to do what you have to do even though it's not recommended.

> Take the belt off and attempt this?

No, leave the belt on to get it back to where you started turning at. Hopefully either the cams will be where they are supposed to be or the crankshaft will. You should have a J-series engine in your Pilot (3.5L V6). I did a writeup for this exact procedure on [a forum](https://acurazine.com/how-tos/a/acura-tl-2009-2014-and-mdx-how-to-replace-timing-belt-and-water-pump-423997) for a company called Internet Brands a few years back (not a promotion, just full disclosure). Pay attention to the correct cam timing marks as there are several on the cog wheels and they are deceiving.

Comment: Thanks again. Definitely making feel better about this situation, I’ll keep you posted.

Comment: @Dre - Also, before you remove the belt, make sure you re-pin the hydraulic tensioner ... It'll make things a LOT easier in the long run.